# Error while executing JavaScript computed expression

Tags: javascript

I have a datatable, I get correct results, but when I click on save button I get the following error:

> com.ibm.xsp.exception.EvaluationExceptionEx: Error while executing
>   JavaScript computed expression Error while executing JavaScript
>   computed expression Script interpreter error, line=8, col=19: 'amt' is
>   null

Here is my code:

```
 var samt = requestScope.get("ElectAmt");
 var amt = requestScope.get(docsse1[3]);
 if (samt != null && samt != "") {
     var namt = samt + "," + amt.toString();
 }
 else {
     var namt = amt.toString()
 };
 requestScope.put("ElectAmt", namt);
 print(requestScope.get("ElectAmt"));
 docsse1[3];
```

Comment: Read errors when you get them, they are often helpful. For example `line=8, col=19: 'amt' is null`  - this tends to mean that `amt` is `null`. So you'd want to check for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error indicates at line 8, column 19 
amt.toString() is causing the error

amt seems to be null so evaluating null.toString() is throwing the error. Check whether amt is not null before executing this step